# Efficient computation of leading eigenvector of a matrix product of the form $ADA^T$, where $D$ is diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix, algorithms, eigenvalues

Let $A=[A_1|\ldots|A_m] \in \mathbb R^{n \times m}$ with $n \gg m \gg 1$ and $D=\text{diag}(d_1,\ldots,d_m)$ where $d_1,\ldots,d_m > 0$, and consider the $n\times n$ positive-definite matrix $X=\sum_{i=1}^m d_i A_iA_i^T=ADA^T$.

## Question

What is an efficient way to compute the leading eigenvector of $X$ without forming the product $ADA^T$ ?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that multiplication by a diagonal matrix is computationally easy, we can write it as:
$$
ADA^T = (A\sqrt{D})(\sqrt{D}^TA^T) = BB^T
$$
where $B=A\sqrt{D}$. Motivated by the fact that the left-singular vectors of $B$ are a set of orthonormal eigenvectors of $BB^T$, we can further proceed:
$$
B = U\Sigma V^T
$$
The first columns $m$ columns of $U$ (corresponding to $m$ highest singular values) should correspond to the first $m$ eigenvectors of $ADA^T$. Since you only want the leading eigenvector, this will suffice.

Here is a short MATLAB code to realize the idea:

```
m = 5; d = 3;
A = randn(m,d); % A is a random matrix - note that it can have negatives
D = diag(rand(d,1)); % just a random diagonal that is positive
[V, ~] = eigs(A*D*A', d); % what we actually like to have
[U, ~, ~] = svd(A*sqrt(D),'eco'); % the variant avoiding the product
```

A sample run of the code above produces the following $U$ and $V$:

$$
U = \begin{bmatrix}
 -0.4276  &  0.0746 &  -0.6573  \\
   -0.3001  &  0.2736 &   0.6797 \\
   -0.5469  &  0.5083 &  -0.1503 \\
   -0.4068 &   0.0579  &  0.2730 \\
   -0.5124 &  -0.8111 &   0.0941
\end{bmatrix}\quad
V = \begin{bmatrix}
-0.4276 &  -0.0746  &  0.6573 \\
   -0.3001 &  -0.2736 &  -0.6797 \\
   -0.5469 &  -0.5083 &   0.1503 \\
   -0.4068 &  -0.0579 &  -0.2730 \\
   -0.5124 &   0.8111 &  -0.0941
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Note the sign ambiguity. Signs of the vectors are arbitrary for the eigen-decomposition anyway. If you like to get the single leading eigenvector, another option is to directly replace the last line with:

`[U, ~, ~] = svds(A*sqrt(D),1);`

Comment: Great, thanks. I also got to a similar idea based on power iterations. This will be super efficient since applying the matrix $X=ADA^T$  to a vector $v$ gives $Xv=A(d\circ (Av))$ which can be done efficiently (more precisely, in $\mathcal O(mn)$ flops) without ever forming the matrix product $ADA^T$